# Pass parameters from view to model in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

In a joomla custom made component there are multiple posts on a page, and every post contains multiple comment, so in view i want to call comments by post id. please suggest a good method to make it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options.  The first, is to attach the comment id as a URL paramater and retrieve it within the model as needed like so:

```
$comment_id = JRequest::getApplication()->input->get('comment_id');
```

If you wish to pass in a parameter when calling the model from the view class, you need to get an instance of the MVC path model instead of using the short cut method.  So, instead of using this in the JView class:

```
 $this->items = $this->get('Items');
```

You would do this instead:

```
$model = $this->getModel();
$this->items = $model->getItems($comment_id);
```

Hope this helps.